# Orchard non-content one-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I kind of new to Orchard. What I'm trying to achieve here is relationship between my Entity. So basically **ApiConfigurationRecord** should have a **list of ApiParameterRecord**. But when I execute the action, nothing is being save. Plus, if it save, hopefully it will lazy-load its child automatically. By the way, I'm trying to non-content way (no ContentPart or ContentPartRecord).

Ok these are my codes:

```
public class ApiConfigurationRecord
{
    public ApiConfigurationRecord()
    {
        if (Parameters == null)
            Parameters = new List<ApiParameterRecord>();
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ApiParameterRecord> Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class ApiParameterRecord
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Migrations : DataMigrationImpl
{
    public int Create()
    {
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("ApiConfigurationRecord", table => table
            .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
            .Column<string>("Name", column=> column.NotNull())
            .Column<string>("Description", column => column.WithLength(500))
            );

        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("ApiParameterRecord", table => table
            .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
            .Column<int>("ApiConfigurationRecord_Id")
            .Column<string>("Name", column => column.NotNull())
            );

        return 1;
    }
}
```

My controller action:

```
    public ActionResult TestInsert()
    {

        var record = new ApiConfigurationRecord() { Name = "Test 1", Description = "Some descripton" };
        record.Parameters.Add(new ApiParameterRecord() { Name = "Param1" });
        this.ApiConfigurationRepository.Create(record);

        return Content("Inserted");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually link the two items.

```
public class ApiParameterRecord
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ApiConfigurationRecord ApiConfigurationRecord { get; set; }
}
```

As for creating, I wouldn't assume it would automatically create the child items, but I'm not sure. Try this:

```
var record = new ApiConfigurationRecord() { Name = "Test 1", Description = "Some descripton" };
this.ApiConfigurationRepository.Create(record);
var child1 = new ApiParameterRecord() { Name = "Param1", ApiConfigurationRecord = record };
ApiParameterRepository.Create(child1);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works out. By the way, got some new problem. Whenever I try call the TestInsert() action, the first time I call data got inserted, but after that, it did not insert. I have to wait for some times, and run again, it works well again. Seems like the 2nd time, the system load the page from cache or something. Do you know why this happening?

Comment: You are only showing a 1-1 relationship here. You need to create a table to accommodate your IList<ApiParameterRecord>

Comment: @dausdashsan try disabling OutputCache in the modules section

Comment: actually, the problem is more likely database cache via syscache. bug here: https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20071. I think the answer is don't use syscache, it's just not worth it :)